# Dividing thousands number for the field

Tags: html, textfield

When I'm texting the number in my text (or number) field I need the number to be divided by thousands with a comma.

**Example**

```
 1. instead of it saying “1000” make it say “1,000”.
 2. “1000000” make it say “1,000,000”.
```

Comment: This link could be of some help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Script**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.Amount', function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
});
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/w2t97yoa/1/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.Amount', function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
Enter Amount:<input class="Amount" type="Amount" />
</form>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This could help you

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var numberinput=document.getElementById('number');
  numberinput.addEventListener('change',changedValue);
}

function changedValue(){
  var input=this.value
  var number=parseInt(input,10);
  if(number>=1000)
    {
      
    var numbersArray = input.toString().split(".");
    numbersArray[0] = numbersArray[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    this.value= numbersArray.join(".");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" >
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

      // skip for arrow keys
      if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

      // format number
      $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
        ;
      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input class="number">
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dannibla/uqh3q01s/)